# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' in heroku platform

Tags: heroku, deployment, deep-learning, streamlit

I deployed my model in Heroku but the below-mentioned attribute error is appearing in the web app.
The heroku and streamlit platforms are not able to unpack my .h5 model for classification purposes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOCmH.png
I don't know what requirements to specify to avoid this error.

Thank you.

```py
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import cv2

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
st.header("Artificial Vision for indoor navigation")
st.subheader("Detecting doors,furnitures, stairs beforehand and prevent accidents")
loaded_model=load_model("vision1.h5")
FRAME_WINDOW = st.image([])

if st.checkbox("Run"):
    webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    classes = ['stairs','furniture',"door"]

    # loop through frames
    while webcam.isOpened():
            status, frame = webcam.read()
            face_crop=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
            face_crop = cv2.resize(face_crop, (300,300))
            face_crop = face_crop.astype("float") / 255.0
            face_crop = img_to_array(face_crop)
            face_crop = np.expand_dims(face_crop, axis=0)

            conf = loaded_model.predict(face_crop)[0] # model.predict return a 2D matrix, ex: [[9.9993384e-01 7.4850512e-05]]

            idx = np.argmax(conf)
            label = classes[idx]

            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, conf[idx] * 100)

            face_cropped=cv2.putText(frame, label, (140, 60),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            print("label: ",label,"probability: ", loaded_model.predict(face_crop)[0])

            iml=face_cropped
            FRAME_WINDOW.image(iml)
                        
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Attach the relevant code as well

Comment: yeah i attached it now

Comment: Code. Not image.

Comment: please check now

Comment: is it possible to unpack .h5 model files in heroku with streamlit ??

Comment: did mention all the packages you used in requirements.txt with the correct version